# What is the advantage of using a UISplitViewController instead of just creating a single UIViewController with 2 subviews

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6

For an iPad app, I realize that having a UISplitViewController allows you to embed childViewControllers inside a parentViewController and the childViewControllers are able to control each of the left and right subviews. However, I was wondering if there is any intrinsic advantage to doing that versus just using a UIViewController that acts as the ViewController for the left and right subviews?

Answer (score 1):

The main advantage to writing your own instead of using UISplitViewController is that you can customize it however you need. The built-in UISplitViewController can't be used as a child view controller, which may be a requirement depending on your app.

Keep in mind that if you don't need anything special, you should stick with what Apple has already provided. The less code you have to maintain, the better. Having said that, it actually doesn't take that much code to roll your own. My custom implementation is about 250 lines and features all the same delegate methods and even the presentation gestures (swipe right to show, swipe left/tap detail to hide).

Comment: Thanks for your answer Eric. Are you able to share your implementation ? I need custom gestures and also custom animations on the views so I figured that it's better to roll my own but I wanted to look at a few examples done by others first.

Answer (score 0):

> However, I was wondering if there is any intrinsic advantage to doing that versus just using a UIViewController that acts as the ViewController for the left and right subviews?

1. You won't have to rewrite all the boilerplate code.
2. It's probably better designed and has less bugs than a quick hack whipped up manually.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest advantage is going to be relying on a framework that has already been written and will probably be improved on in the future.

The split view controller went through a big upgrade between iOS5 and iOS6 with how the navigation side was displayed while the device is in portrait and if you used their framework its an automatic upgrade.

With that said if you wanted some custom look or functionality then it can be worth writing your own although breaking common behavior can be confusing to users depending on what you do.